# Window, Cordova ---a lot of error when build project -.-

Tags: android, cordova, build

I'm tring to start a project in Cordova but every time I Run the command " Cordova build Android --release " it gives me 3-4 errors. I have a number of questions that hope you could answer:

1. In the command prompt, from which folder the app start command "build " ?
2. Are there other commands to do before "build "? (except from those of creation project).

The errors are :

- error : Spawm cms ENOENT
- Error build of the platform "location " comand filed with exit code 1
- command Filed with exit code 1

[this](http://postimg.org/image/l7brfpgu9/) Image should make it clearer.

Comment: you need node.js installed in your system before using these commands.

Comment: try this link :-  http://phonegap.com/install/

Comment: yuo are not open the img ? Node.j is already installed

Comment: Phonegap do same problem when start " phone build android "